# In jquery ajax send json which contains FormData

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to upload file using jquery ajax. Ajax calling time also I want send file in json look like this:

```
 var uploadFileData = new FormData();
    $('input.file-upload').on('change', function (event) {
        uploadFileData.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
    });
    var json = {
        MainPart: {info1:'inf1', info2:'inf2'},
        DynamicPart: uploadFileData
    };
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: '',
            type: "POST",
            data: json,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            success: function (call_back_data) {
                call_back(call_back_data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('There is error');
            }
        });
```

Can I send FormData in json and how can I get file stream in ASP.net server side???
If it isn't possible is there other solution to send information and file???

Comment: Why using jQuery for uploading file? I would suggest to use `HttpPostedFile`, create a Razor Form and after file submission, keep in storage image's path from the server.

Comment: I use it in SharePoint Visual Web part and my opportunities not so big. Also I don't want my page load in time file upload.